# View state of a frozen generator while debugging

Tags: python, pycharm, python-2.x, pdb

Take e.g. the following sample code:

```
def gen():
    for i in range(5): yield i

def main():
    for j in gen():
        print j
```

When the execution point is in `main()` (e.g. on the `print` line), can I somehow examine the state of `gen()` (i.e. the value of `i`) ? Unlike a regular function, it doesn't appear on the call stack.

Comment: But `j` is on the call stack.

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm not interested in `j`. Yes, in this particular case, they are equal, but with another code, this may not be the case. This code is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because there's no way to access the generator object, and because pdb doesn't support debugging a suspended stack frame. If you'd saved the generator object, you could inspect its `gi_frame` manually, though:

```
>>> def gen():
...     for i in range(5):
...         yield i
...
>>> def main():
...     g = gen()
...     for j in g:
...         import pdb
...         pdb.set_trace()
...         print j
...
>>> main()
> <stdin>(6)main()
(Pdb) p g.gi_frame.f_locals['i']
0
```

Here, I've accessed the generator's suspended frame through `gi_frame`, then accessed the frame's `locals()` through `f_locals`. (Like with `locals()`, don't try to modify `f_locals` manually, though.)

Comment: Okay, `pdb` doesn't support accessing the suspended generator. Does Python itself do? `pdb` can evaluate any Python expression, after all. E.g. something like `sys._getframe()`, or something in objects associated with the current frame.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: The reference to the generator is in the `main` frame's value stack, a part of the frame not exposed to Python code.